# Windows Macro + Hot Key - Paste Without Formatting

Tags: windows, macros, hotkeys

Not sure if this appropriate to put as a question or not? It's sort of a scripting question I think. Just down vote me if not :p

Basically, what I'm looking for is a way to push a windows hotkey and have whatever text is in the clipboard be stripped of formatting. An example of what the macro could do:

- I push (whatever hotkey combo here)
- open notepad.exe
- Paste to notepad from clipboard
- Select all text in notepad
- Copy/Cut all text from notepad
- Close notepad

I'm just wondering if someone has done something like this before, or knows how it could be accomplished. I think this could be a huge time-saver for almost anyone. I find myself doing this all the time when cutting and pasting between different office applications, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard of Puretext, it appears to do what you're looking for:

http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! Just downloaded and working ... this will make my life a lot easier, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of emulating hotkeys to control Notepad, you can write code to implement what Notepad implements when it gets text from the clipboard: i.e. use the clipboard API to get the clipboard contents as unformatted text.

Comment: Cool idea. Is there any way you provide more info on how you would implement this ... (write a script? If so, what language? What would call that script?). Not that you weren't clear, I'm just not too familiar with how you would accomplish something like this.

Comment: @JasonStoltz - The [Windows Clipboard API](http://www.google.ca/#q=windows+clipboard+api) can be accessed using several programming languages (for example, using C or using C#). It's introduced [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648709(v=vs.85).aspx). I expect that an office application will write to the clipboard using several formats simultaneously (e.g. text and others). What you want is an application which, when it's run, removes every format except the text format from the cliboard ... and, run this application just before you paste something.

Comment: Haven't really tried this out, but it seems like a reasonable solution so I'll mark it as the correct answer. If I do get a chance to try it, I will add any feedback I have to this answer.

Comment: @JasonStoltz - An alterative would be code which a) gets a copy of the the text version of the data from the clipboard b) pastes that text version into the target application/document, without altering the contents of the clipboard. The advantage of this alternative would be that it leaves several/all formats in the clipboard: as later the user might want to paste the non-text version of the data from the clipboard. The disadvantage is needing to implement an application-specific paste into the target application/document, instead of just working with the application-independent clipboard API.

Answer (score 0):

Try **AutoHotKey** to make a tiny and easy script to do what you want.
You will find a powerful windows interface macro programing tool.